# Transcode Videos in Azure to AVI container (YUV420 format)

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

We have a requirement to transcode videos to the below format:

- Standard AVI container
- Video file in YUV420 format, min 15FPS
- Uncompressed PCM audio (if available)
- 4:3 or 16:9 with square pixel ratio (320x240 or 640x480 recommended)
- No borders -or- black-strip borders

On Media Encoder documentation we did not find output support for AVI container (or YUV420 format). 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-media-encoder-standard-formats

We wanted to confirm if there is any way to use Azure for this transcoding need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after posting on the microsoft forums:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/738f28d2-fd22-48a9-9106-319ac85ca5ea/transcode-videos-in-azure-to-avi-container-yuv420-format?forum=MediaServices#738f28d2-fd22-48a9-9106-319ac85ca5ea

The Premium Encoder has this support

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-premium-workflow-encoder-formats